# React-based UI framework recommendations for complex, interactive applications

Tags: reactjs, frameworks, material-design

I am about to embark on a project to develop a Web-based interface that has very high complexity, specifically around interactivity, and I wanted to ask which UI frameworks would be best to leverage for this purpose.

By complex and interactive I mean something like Figma, Miro, Google Drive, etc. Experience will be mostly full-screen and I'll need to have dockable dialogs, multi-level menus, tool palettes, status indicators etc.

I wonder if there are well-supported frameworks that take care of some common "desktop application-like" behaviors as primitives, such as top and side menus, layout, dialog drag-and-drop with snapping.
It feels to me that there as very rich applications like these become more common, some of these challenges may be already resolved, instead of having to implement this from scratch over component frameworks such as Material UI.

I hope the question makes sense - I feel I lack more specific vocabulary to explain what I need.

Thanks for your patience and guidance,

Ale